# ASP.Net Core: IIS Active Directory Authentication - Not using Pool Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Our ASP.NET Core app works well with Windows Authentication, correctly securing the app with:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "ABC\\MyGroup")]
```

However, when we move the app to another server, the Pool the app is running under doesn't have rights to access Active Directory. In Setup.cs how can I tell ASP.Net Core to use a specific account to access Active Directory to authenticate requests with.

I am not asking about Impersonation in the app, the app needs to simple access AD so that it can determine if a user can access a Controller

```
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.Configure<IISOptions>(options => {
            options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
            options.ForwardClientCertificate = true;
            options.AuthenticationDisplayName = "EnterAccount";
        });
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. ASP.NET Core doesn't have any AD / Windows Auth support per se. The IIS is the one which passes the identity down to the app via IIS Integration middleware. The only other way to use windows auth with ASP.NET Core is to use http.sys (formerly know as WebListener) as platform (instead of kestrel). But then you can't host it in IIS and have to self-host it. Your issue is not related to ASP.NET Core per see, you have to look that your IIS has the necessary permissions to do that. ASP.NET Core not involved in it

Comment: Not an expert in IIS, but imho the only way is to allow the app pool to access the AD or create a new app pool (if you don't want other apps in that pool get this kind of permission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Add this to your Web.config

```
  <aspNetCore forwardWindowsAuthToken="true"
```

I blogged about a complete [solution here](https://ianvink.wordpress.com/2018/06/06/asp-net-core-2-quick-and-dirty-windows-authentication/).